# Can I use a .TTF font within a SVG file?

Tags: python, svg, fonts, truetype

I am writing a program in Python that will save a drawing (text and shapes) in .SVG format.

The SVG document works with installed fonts (Windows) and it works with Google fonts using code like so

```
<defs>
    <style type='text/css'>@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Schoolbell');
    </style>
</defs>
```

But I have not been able to instruct the SVG to use a local .TTF font file.

Is there a solution to this ? 
Oh by the way , the file is not for use on the web, so CSS techniques won't do.

Comment: If the file is not for use on the web, what are you using to view it? Presumably that has some limitations or more likely security restrictions that prevent loading random files.

Comment: @Robert Longson I have tried Inkscape , Gimp and browsers.

Comment: browsers generally won't load another file from a first file, presumably neither will Inkscape or Gimp.

Comment: Hmmm why not, doesn't sound like a security issue. These are font files. I've used <font-face-uri> but I couldn't get it to work. Wondering if it works at all or is ignored.